# Is there a way to conditionally render content using onClick in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, rendering

Is there a way to achieve conditionally rendered content below but instead of using {renderAuthButton()} in the return statement, I want to achieve running renderAuthButton() with onCLick instead?

```
class App extends Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    let {isLoggedIn} = this.state;

    const renderAuthButton = () => {
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        return <button>Logout</button>;
      } else {
        return <button>Login</button>;
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>
          This is a Demo showing several ways to implement Conditional Rendering in React.
        </h1>
        {renderAuthButton()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand your need but to render conditionally, you can do something like that

```js
state = {
  show: false,
}
<div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.setState((prev) => { show: !prev.show })}>Toggle</button>
        {this.state.show && <MyComponent />}
      </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I want to have a button that when clicked achieves the filtering action...i.e when clicked only show data that has a condition and when clicked again shows all data ...something like that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do but this is how you would conditionally render content in react:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      show: false
    }
    
    this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this);
  }
  
  toggleShow(){
    this.setState({show: ! this.state.show})
  }
 
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleShow}>Filter Content</button>
        
        {this.state.show ? (
          <p>This content is conditionally shown</p>
        ) : (
          <p>The content is now hidden</p>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```